# How to get values of rows and columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables.

1. Student Table

[image]

2. Property Table

[image]

3. Result Table

[image]

How can I get the value of Student Table and the property ID of the column fron the Property table and merge that into the Result table?

Any advice would be helpful.

Update #1:

I tried using Christian Moen 's suggestion, this is what i get.

[image]

Comment: You need to join these tables by its foreign keys and create a relation as; select .. .. from student, result, property where student.ID = result.stuID and result.propID = property.id

Comment: thanks @ChristianMoen for the reply, but still i'm not able to get the required output. please see my updated question

Comment: This is not the right solution. You need to match the column names with property names. Simple approach would be to hardcode the id's and the column names in the query. The detailed approach would be to use meta data which might get complicated.

Comment: Also..do you already have the results table or do you need the results in that format? In your update, you are joining with the results table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [`UNPIVOT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) the `Student`'s columns first, to get the columns (properties names) in one column as rows. Then `join` with the `Property` table based on the property name like this:

```
WITH UnPivoted
AS
(
  SELECT ID, value,col
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT ID,
      CAST(Name AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS Name, 
      CAST(Class AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS Class,
      CAST(ENG AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS ENG,
      CAST(TAM AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS TAM,
      CAST(HIN AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS HIN,
      CAST(MAT AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS MAT,
      CAST(PHY AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS PHY
    FROM Student 
  ) AS s
  UNPIVOT
  (value FOR col IN 
        ([Name], [class], [ENG], [TAM], [HIN], [MAT], [PHY])
  )AS unpvt
)
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY u.ID,PropertyID) AS ID,
  p.PropertyID,
  u.Value,
  u.ID AS StudID
FROM Property AS p
INNER JOIN UnPivoted AS u ON p.PropertyName = u.col;
```

For the first `ID`, I used the ranking function `ROW_NUMBER()` to generate this sequence id.

---

This will give the exact results that you are looking for.

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2a6ee/4)**:

```
| ID | PropertyID |  Value | StudID |
|----|------------|--------|--------|
|  1 |          1 |   Jack |      1 |
|  2 |          2 |     10 |      1 |
|  3 |          3 |     89 |      1 |
|  4 |          4 |     88 |      1 |
|  5 |          5 |     45 |      1 |
|  6 |          6 |    100 |      1 |
|  7 |          7 |     98 |      1 |
|  8 |          1 |   Jill |      2 |
|  9 |          2 |     10 |      2 |
| 10 |          3 |     89 |      2 |
| 11 |          4 |     99 |      2 |
| 12 |          5 |    100 |      2 |
| 13 |          6 |     78 |      2 |
| 14 |          7 |     91 |      2 |
| 15 |          1 | Trevor |      3 |
| 16 |          2 |     12 |      3 |
| 17 |          3 |    100 |      3 |
| 18 |          4 |     50 |      3 |
| 19 |          5 |     49 |      3 |
| 20 |          6 |     94 |      3 |
| 21 |          7 |    100 |      3 |
| 22 |          1 |    Jim |      4 |
| 23 |          2 |      8 |      4 |
| 24 |          3 |    100 |      4 |
| 25 |          4 |     91 |      4 |
| 26 |          5 |     92 |      4 |
| 27 |          6 |    100 |      4 |
| 28 |          7 |    100 |      4 |
```

Comment: Thanks ReadyFe, this is exactly what i need. Just curious, is it possible to make the column names dynamic, instead of using directly. lets say, in future, i have added a new column GEO in Student table and property table, i need to add the GEO in the query, right?

Answer (score 0):

Other option is to use of `apply`  if you don't want to go `unpivot` way

```
select row_number() over (order by (select 1)) ID, p.PropertyID [PropID], a.Value, a.StuID 
from Student s
cross apply
(
    values (s.ID, 'Name', s.Name),
           (s.ID, 'Class', cast(s.Class as varchar)),
           (s.ID, 'ENG', cast(s.ENG as varchar)),
           (s.ID, 'TAM', cast(s.TAM as varchar)),
           (s.ID, 'HIN', cast(s.HIN as varchar)),
           (s.ID, 'MAT', cast(s.MAT as varchar)),
           (s.ID, 'PHY', cast(s.PHY as varchar))
) as a(StuID, Property, Value)
join Property p on p.PropertyName = a.Property
```

Comment: 'Name','Class'.. were hardcoded right, is there any way to make them dynamic?

Comment: @RanjithVaradan that will be very strange way or fully dynamic way hence this will be very easy and smarter way.

Comment: @RanjithVaradan and if you have periodically update or add the column name then go with above with dynamic way else use above.